# GAE DataStore Retrieving Entities by Keys and Filter by Dates - Slow Performance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I use NDB query to retrieve entities by a list of keys by IN operator and then filter by Dates. The query was broken into several sub queries, which is written in doc. and running in sequence instead of in parallel.

```
class Post(ndb.Model):
  modified_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()

# query
posts = Post.query(
  Post.key.IN(keys),
  Post.modified_date >= start_date,
  Post.modified_date <= end_date).fetch()
```

The query profiling graph shows sequentially run sub queries. It takes about 0.3 seconds for 25 keys. The query latency is linear to number of keys to get.

[image: query profiling]

Is there any way to optimize the query, and what is the best practice to retrieve entities by keys and filter by date range?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the IN operator.

For each key in keys GAE will perform an individual query.

From the GAE docs:

> The IN operator also performs multiple queries: one for each item in the specified list, with all other filters unchanged and the IN filter replaced with an equality (=) filter. The results are merged in order of the items in the list. If a query has more than one IN filter, it is performed as multiple queries, one for each possible combination of values in the IN lists.
>
> A single query containing not-equal (!=) or IN operators is limited to
>   no more than 30 subqueries.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/queries

The modified_date is ok, because there is an index and therefore is efficient.

Comment: Thank you. I understand there will be sub queries for IN operator. What surprise me is t he sub queries are executed sequentially instead of in parallel.

Is there some way to make the sub queries executed in parallel?

Comment: Yep. Instead of calling ferch. Call fetch_async

Comment: I tried to call fetch_async().get_result() and still see plenty of sub queries, which query exactly one entity, running sequentially. The same as fetch().

posts = Post.query(conditions).fetch_async().get_result(), 

Do you mean I should implement my own version of IN operator by query each entity async and merge the results?

Comment: Are you on production or in the develpment server? Have you tried in production?

Comment: I tried in production and get the profiling graph from StackDriver Trace.

Comment: Then I don't know why. Sorry I can't helo more